# DWR - Broken reflection Exception in Jetty 9

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty, dwr

We are currently developing an application using DWR 3.0.RC2 deployed to Tomcat, in which DWR is configured and working as expected. We are considering switching to use Jetty, and I'm working on the migration process. However, I'm encountering exceptions on the server which are causing DWR to not work, and was wondering if anyone had encountered this or had suggestions (in case I missed some configuration, etc.

The application loads and launches. When browsed to, we get an error in the Browser console, and DWR data is not pushed when expected. The Server logs show stacktraces during each request with a DWR push.

The current deployment (working) is on Tomcat 7.0.21, and we are trying to move to Jetty 9.2.3.v20140905 (not working). Can someone possibly provide some pointers?

**Jetty Configuration:**

100% default (is freshly downloaded for this use), except ran `java -jar start.jar --add-to-startd=https` to enable HTTPS.

**Relevant web.xml configuration:**

```
<servlet>
  <description>Direct Web Remoting Servlet</description>
  <display-name>DWR Servlet</display-name>
  <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.directwebremoting.servlet.DwrServlet</servlet-class>

  <!-- We're currently using Java annotations instead of a separate dwr.xml 
       config file. -->
  <init-param>
      <!-- The "classes" servlet parameter must provide a comma-separated 
           list of the fully-qualified class names of all annotated classes 
           to be used with DWR. -->
      <param-name>classes</param-name>
      <param-value>
          org.ourdomain.ourapp.ApplicationDWR, 
          org.ourdomain.ourapp.DataImportDWR
      </param-value>
  </init-param>

    <!-- Remove this unless you want to use active reverse ajax -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>activeReverseAjaxEnabled</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <!-- By default DWR creates application scope objects when they are first
    used. This creates them when the app-server is started -->
    <init-param>
      <param-name>initApplicationScopeCreatorsAtStartup</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>

  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>dwr-invoker</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/dwr/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

**Errors:**

*Client:*

```
Error: Object {name: "dwr.engine.missingData", message: "No data received from server"}
```

*Server:*

```
13:12:09,621 ERROR JettyContinuationSleeper:181 - Broken reflection
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.directwebremoting.util.Continuation.resume(Continuation.java:107)
        at org.directwebremoting.server.jetty.JettyContinuationSleeper.wakeUp(JettyContinuationSleeper.java:177)
        at org.directwebremoting.impl.TimedAlarm$1.run(TimedAlarm.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like DWR hasn't updated their [support for Jetty since 7.0.1](http://svn.directwebremoting.org/dwr/trunk/core/api/lib/) (which was 5 years ago).

There seems to be a [Servlet3 support option](http://svn.directwebremoting.org/dwr/trunk/core/impl/main/java/org/directwebremoting/server/servlet3/), can you use/configure for that instead? (Jetty 9 is a valid Servlet 3.1 container)